# Почему error TextInputLayout увеличивает размер базового view?

Tags: android, android-fragment, android-layout

Доброго времени суток!

Если использовать фрагмент внутри фрагмента, то при отображении ошибок через TextInputLayout, FrameLayout, который является контейнером для дочернего фрагмента, слишком сильно увеличивается в размере.

Почему так происходит и как этого избежать?

Пример программы я оставил здесь:
https://github.com/Lacredin/SampleErrorTextInputLayout.git

Чтобы отобразить error надо щёлкнуть на текстовое поле. В примере хорошо видно, что FrameLayout начинает становиться больше вложенного фрагмента с отображение каждой, новой ошибки.

Урезано и схематично верстка выглядит так:

```
        <FrameLayout 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="false">
        //Этот FrameLayout является контейнером для первого фрагмента, далее схематичное содержание первого фрагмента
        <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

            //какие-то блоки
            <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
                android:id="@+id/nestedScrollViewPassport"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:fillViewport="true">
                //какие-то блоки
                    <FrameLayout
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:background="@android:color/holo_red_dark">
                        //Этот FrameLayout является контейнером для вторго фрагмента, вложенного в первый фрагмент, далее схематичное его содержание
                            <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                                <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    ndroid.support.design:hintAnimationEnabled="true"
                                    android.support.design:hintEnabled="true"
                                    android.support.design:layout_marginTop="16dp">
                                    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
                                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
                                </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

                                <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    ndroid.support.design:hintAnimationEnabled="true"
                                    android.support.design:hintEnabled="true"
                                    android.support.design:layout_marginTop="16dp">
                                    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
                                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
                                </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

                                <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                                    android:id="@+id/fragment_passport_input_subdivision_info"
                                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android.support.design:hintAnimationEnabled="true"
                                    android.support.design:hintEnabled="true"
                                    android.support.design:layout_marginTop="16dp">

                                    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
                                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
                                </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
                                <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                                    android:id="@+id/fragment_passport_input_date_info"
                                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android.support.design:hintAnimationEnabled="true"
                                    android.support.design:hintEnabled="true">

                                    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
                                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
                                </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
                                <Button
                                    android:id="@+id/fragment_passport_input_button_save"

                                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
                            </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

                    </FrameLayout>
                </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
            </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
        </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
    </FrameLayout>
```

Помогите пожалуйста понять в чём дело!

Comment: И дело не в многочисленных `marginTop`?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема в том, что Вы не до конца понимаете как работает ConstraintLayout, я и сам плохо понимаю :-) но вот нашел у Вас немного лишнего в разметке.

1. В Вашем случае Вам не нужен вертикальный bias, еще и установленый в 0.`bias` указывает с каким соотношением, касательно указаных сторон будет располагаться виджет.
2. Второе, это то, что Вы указали `constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"`, что значит что Ваш `FrameLayout` будет стремиться притянуть свою нижнюю часть к нижней части `ConstraintLayout`'а, а раз у Вас высота все равно установлена в `wrap_content`, то это лишнее и может создавать казусы.
3. Вообще лучше убирать все лишнее из кода разметки, и стараться делать ее максимально простой с минимальным количеством вложенностей.

   Советую посмотреть сюда :
   https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/constraint/ConstraintLayout 

   А также обратить внимание на эту статью, второй пункт(хоть и староватая, но суть уловить можно): https://habr.com/post/279979/

Решение вашей проблемы смотрите ниже (все в фрагменте `fragment_blank`).

[image: до изменений]
**Ваш код --->**

```
<FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/fragment_passport_input_box_fragment"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
            app:layout_constrainedHeight="true"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/fragment_passport_input_type_document_box"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />
```

[image: после изменений]
**ТУТ рабочий код --->**

```
 <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/fragment_passport_input_box_fragment"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                android:background="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/fragment_passport_input_type_document_box" />
```

А вообще тут проблема в `app:layout_constrainedHeight="true"`, мне пока не понятно как оно работает, но что то вроде как ограничивает `wrap_content`. но в  большинстве случаев лучше не использовать, тем более если не знаеш для чего.

Comment: Я знаю для чего нужен app:layout_constrainedHeight="true". Он заставляет применять ограничения к layout. Например такие ограничения, как минимальная высоты, без него минимальная высота заменяется размером контента.
Проблема в побочном эффекте, который вызывает этот параметр.